# ssh接続鍵認証をwindowsとmacでしたい

Tags: ssh

こんにちは、
家でも仕事が出来るように、リモート設定をしています。

リモート用のPCはmacで会社の環境と同じようにして作成しています。

いつもは、会社のwindowsのPCからssh接続して、相手サーバーのグローバルIPを打ちこみ
秘密鍵を入れてアクセスしています。

今回macでssh接続してwindowsで使用している秘密鍵を使ってアクセスしようと思っています。

普通につなげることが可能なのでしょうか？

**追記1**
つなげることができました。つながらなかった原因はコピーした`id_rsa`ファイルのパーミッションが違うかったからです。600にしたらつながりました。
こんな感じで

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa username@example.com
```

長いのでもっと短くできないのでしょうか？
そしてセキュリティの面でも考えないといけませんので鍵を増やさないといけません。

Comment: 追記された内容 (もっと短く～) は元質問とは離れる内容なので、別質問に分けるべきだと思います (`alias` やバッチファイルなんかを用意する形になりそうですが)。

Comment: 追記の質問に答えたいのですがこのご投稿の中でやるとしっちゃかめっちゃかになりそうなので分けて新しくご投稿いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 改めて質問を見返すと、真の質問は **mac から ssh 接続ができない** で、その答えは **コピーした id_rsa ファイルのパーミッションが適切でなかったから** 、ではありませんか？状況説明がきちんとできていないように思います。 / 「自分のやりたいこと」を起点にするのではなく、「何に困っているのか」をベースにこの場合は質問を組み立てるべきなのかなと。

Comment: わかりました。これから気を付けます。何に困っているかですね。

Answer (score 5):

SSH のプロトコルは Windows や Mac といった環境に依存していないので、同じ秘密鍵を使って Mac からアクセスすること自体は可能です。

しかし、あまりオススメしません。というのも、Windows だけ使わなくなったような状況で、その Windows から今後アクセスできなくなったと保証するのが難しいからです（キーペアの無効化をしたくなりますが、この状況で無効化してしまうと Mac からもアクセスできなくなります）。また、その秘密鍵をどうやって Windows から Mac へ安全に移動させるかという問題もあります。

このため、その Mac のために新しくキーペアを作成し、その秘密鍵を使う方が便利です。こうするとたとえば今後その Mac を使わなくなった場合や Mac を紛失した際に、そのキーペアだけ無効化すれば良くなります。

Comment: 確かにセキュリティが甘すぎますね。それぞれに鍵を持たせようかと考えます。